# Using Robocopy in VS Postbuild - Automatically Overwrite When Moving Files

Tags: visual-studio, robocopy

I tried the following postbuild command in VS to copy all the dlls and other related files into a centralized folder:

```
robocopy $(TargetDir) $(TargetDir)Bin *.dll *.pdb *.xml  /MOVE
```

It successfully moves them if the Bin folder doesn't have those files yet. But after the second execution, the files are not moved. I am suspecting that it fails because the files in there already exist. Is there a switch to force overwrite without prompting? I looked at the possible switches for robocopy and can't really find the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that Robocopy is refusing to move files that it detects are the same on subsequent runs.  You should be able to force it to do so with the /IS (include same) and /IT (include tweaked) flags - i.e.,

```
robocopy $(TargetDir) $(TargetDir)Bin *.dll *.pdb *.xml /IS /IT /MOVE
```